# Raw Pointers not producing desired effects

Tags: pointers, memory, rust

```
#![feature(ptr_internals)]

use core::ptr::Unique;

struct PtrWrapper {
    id: usize,
    self_reference: Unique<Self>
}

impl PtrWrapper {
    fn new() -> Self {
        let dummy = unsafe {Unique::new_unchecked(std::ptr::null_mut::<PtrWrapper>())};
        let mut ret = Self {id:0, self_reference: dummy };
        let new_ptr = &mut ret as *mut Self;
        debug_print(new_ptr);
        ret.self_reference = Unique::new(new_ptr).unwrap();
        debug_print(ret.self_reference.as_ptr());
        ret
    }

    fn get_id(&self) -> usize {
        self.id.clone()
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("START");
    let mut wrapper = PtrWrapper::new();
    wrapper.id = 10;

    let ptr = wrapper.self_reference.as_ptr();
    unsafe {
        (*ptr).id += 30;
        println!("The next print isn't 40? Garbage bytes");
        debug_print(ptr);

        let tmp = &mut wrapper as *mut PtrWrapper;
        (*tmp).id += 500;

        println!("The next print isn't 540?");
        debug_print(tmp);
    }

    println!("Below debug_print is proof of undefined behavior! Garbage bytes\n");
    debug_print(wrapper.self_reference.as_ptr());


    debug_print(&mut wrapper as *mut PtrWrapper);

    debug_print_move(wrapper);

    println!("Why is the assertion below false?");
    assert_eq!(unsafe{(*ptr).id}, 540);
}

fn debug_print_move(mut wrapper: PtrWrapper) {
    debug_print(&mut wrapper as *mut PtrWrapper);
}

fn debug_print(ptr: *mut PtrWrapper) {
    println!("Address: {:p}", ptr);
    println!("ID: {}\n", unsafe {(*ptr).get_id()});
}
```

The above code should compile fine in rust playground with a nightly selected version. Pay attention to the console outputs.

My question is: Why are the intermittent results not equal to the value I expect them to equal? In the case below, there is no multiple access simultaneously (single threaded), so there aren't any data races. There are, however, implicitly multiple mutable version of the object existing on the stack.

As expected, the memory location of the pointer changes with the `tmp` variable as well as when the entire object is moved into `debug_print_move`. It appears that using the `tmp` pointer works as expected (i.e., adds 500), however, the pointers which are obtained from the `Unique<PtrWrapper>` object seems to point to irrelevant locations in memory.

Comment: You are taking the stack for your pointer, it's UB to use it after the end function `new()`, `ret` go out of scope.

Comment: That is what I began to fear. Would boxing the pointer solve the problem?

Comment: maybe https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/pin/index.html

Answer (score 0):

As Stargateur recommended, in order to solve this problem we need to Pin the object which needs to be self-referential. I ended up using:

```
pin-api = "0.2.1"
```

In cargo.toml instead of `std::pin::pin`. Next, I set this up the struct and its implementation:

```
#![feature(ptr_internals, pin_into_inner, optin_builtin_traits)]
// not available on rust-playground
extern crate pin_api;

use pin_api::{boxed::PinBox, marker::Unpin, mem::Pin};

///test
pub struct PtrWrapper<T>
where
    T: std::fmt::Debug,
{
    ///tmp
    pub obj: T,
    /// pinned object
    pub self_reference: *mut Self,
}

impl<T> !Unpin for PtrWrapper<T> where T: std::fmt::Debug {}

impl<T> PtrWrapper<T>
where
    T: std::fmt::Debug,
{
    ///test
    pub fn new(obj: T) -> Self {
        Self {
            obj,
            self_reference: std::ptr::null_mut(),
        }
    }

    ///test
    pub fn init(mut self: Pin<PtrWrapper<T>>) {
        let mut this: &mut PtrWrapper<T> = unsafe { Pin::get_mut(&mut self) };
        this.self_reference = this as *mut Self;
    }

    /// Debug print
    pub fn print_obj(&self) {
        println!("Obj value: {:#?}", self.obj);
    }
}
```

Finally, the test function:

```
fn main2() {
    unsafe {
        println!("START");

        let mut wrapper = PinBox::new(PtrWrapper::new(10));
        wrapper.as_pin().init();

        let m = wrapper.as_pin().self_reference;

        (*m).obj += 30;
        println!("The next print is 40");
        debug_print(m);

        let tmp = wrapper.as_pin().self_reference;
        (*tmp).obj += 500;

        println!("The next print is 540?");
        debug_print(tmp);

        debug_print(wrapper.self_reference);

        let cpy = PinBox::get_mut(&mut wrapper);
        debug_print_move(cpy);

        std::mem::drop(wrapper);
        println!("Works!");
        assert_eq!(unsafe { (*m).obj }, 540);
    }
}

fn debug_print_move<T>(mut wrapper: &mut PtrWrapper<T>)
where
    T: std::fmt::Debug,
{
    debug_print(&mut *wrapper as *mut PtrWrapper<T>);
}

fn debug_print<T>(ptr: *mut PtrWrapper<T>)
where
    T: std::fmt::Debug,
{
    println!("Address: {:p}", ptr);
    unsafe { (*ptr).print_obj() };
}
```

On a side note, pin-api does not exist on rust playground. You could still use `std::pin::Pin`, however it would require further customization.